# Matlab and PDE:can you model a rubber ball being squeezed between two steel blocks?

Tags: matlab, pde

[image]

I would like to model the compression of a rubber ball, being squeezed between two steel balls.

What i want is to be able to demonstrate the contact areas and the local pressure within these contact areas.

Is that possible? How do you set upp the constraints?

I am new to Matlabs PDE and finite elements. So i just want to know
if this is possible. I have an understanding of modulus, strain, stress et cetera.

Comment: ask in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

while it's possible to model this problem in MATLAB PDE Toolbox, it might not be efficient for contact problems. I recommend using Abaqus CAE instead. To simplify the task, consider a 2D problem with two circles of steel and one of rubber. For constraints, applying two pressure forces symmetrically would be the simplest approach. This allows you to focus solely on the upper part of the system.